# Why isn't this inline javascript blocked by content security policy?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xss, content-security-policy

I have a page that I set the script-src of the content security policy like this:

```
script-src 'self' *.uservoice.com *.intuit.com ajax.googleapis.com localhost:*
```

When I load the page with a hard-coded inline script I have created myself to test, it is blocked like expected:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy         directive: "script-src 'self'
>   *.uservoice.com *.intuit.com ajax.googleapis.com localhost:* ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

However, when I insert a new script tag dynamically, the script isn't blocked, for example, this still executes:

```
$("body").append("<script>alert('xss');</script>")
```

I am using Chrome as the browser here for testing. I was hoping that this script would be blocked as well, since that would really help to prevent xss. Is there something I can change to block this type of script injection as well?

Comment: Why do you need to block this? This is perfectly secure, unless you don't trust your own code that you're appending (in that case, you need to sanitize it).

Comment: Write secure JavaScript?

Comment: jQuery `eval`uates `<script>`s itself that are inserted with it (see the paragraph under "[*Additional Notes*](http://api.jquery.com/append/)"). So, a possible answer could be to not use jQuery where you want the browser to manage it alone.

Comment: @soktinpk So, it won't protect me from errors I might make in sanitization...?

Comment: @user3152280 No, if you don't trust a script, don't run it.

Comment: @user3152280: You shouldn't really be doing any sanitization. If you need to use dynamic values securely, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21428259/413180).

Comment: @user3152280 you want to create some kind of sandbox on your page? If so, you should looking for solutions like [Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/). Anyway, giving users access to jQuery (as of any other 3rd party lib) isn't good idea at all.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski if you made your comment into an answer, i'd accept it, since it answers the question and it is what i needed to know.

Answer (score 3):

The script you add with `append` or `innerHtml` won't be executed unless you use `eval()`. So it's not violating CSP.

> Although this may look like a cross-site scripting attack, the result is harmless. HTML5 specifies that a  tag inserted via innerHTML should not execute. [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

See [script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)

Comment: Note that `.append()` does just that -- "*unless you use eval()*." You should also include the source of content you quote -- ["Security considerations" of `element.innerHTML` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML).