# Safe way to send value from jsp to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, xss

I have to secure a java web application against XSS attacks. There are parts of the code that look like this:

```
<script>
  jsvariable = ${jspvariable}
  use(jsvariable)
<script>
```

My first tough was to do something like this:

```
<script>
  jsvariable = ${fn:escapeXml(jspvariable)}
  use(jsvariable)
<script>
```

But `escapeXml` doesn't avoid XSS inside a script tag. What's the correct way to send a value from jsp to javascript.

Comment: use JSON.parse(theData) if you can

Comment: @dandavis What if the data is `"hello"); alert("XSS");`? This is the kind of scenario I'm trying to defend against.

Comment: Deactivate any inline javascript with csp

Comment: [Use a Content Security Policy and put the JavaScript in external files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428259/secure-way-of-inserting-dynamic-values-in-external-javascript-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your jsp data in a text/json block which will be ignored by the browser:

```
<script id="demo" type="text/json">
  ${jspvariable}
</script>
```

You can then parse the values in your javascript file on dom ready:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML));
```

A XSS injection could lead only to a JSON parse error

Comment: Actually what about this case: 
    `jspvariable = {} </script> <script> alert('XSS');`

Comment: You should combine it with CSP and disallow any inline javascript: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/?redirect_from_locale=de