# Simultaneously sandbox and add JS/HTML to iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, sandbox

I am trying to create an iframe that has JS fire inside of it but does not have access to the parent document. The goal is to have a simple implementation and not include any special libraries. I found that the [HTML5 Sandbox attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) is a viable solution; however, it is proving to be quite difficult to simultaneously sandbox an iframe *and* put JS inside of it.

I have tried:

1. Adding JS to iframe and then sandboxing it from the parent document. **This does not work because JS in iframe fires before the iframe sandbox is applied**
2. Creating iframe and setting HTML with `srcdoc` attribute (ex. `<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" srcdoc="<body><script src='sample1.js'></script><script src='sample2.js'></script></body>"></iframe>`) **This does not work in IE according to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp)**
3. Creating iframe and setting HTML with `src` attribute (ex. `<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="javascript:&quot;<html><body><script src='sample1.js'></script><script src='sample2.js'></script></body></html>&quot;"></iframe`) **This does not work in Firefox 38.0.5 (Mac OS X Yosemite) but works in Chrome 43 & Safari 8.0.4** ..."not working in Firefox" means that it will indeed allow sample2.js to add `<span></span>` to the iframe DOM, but it does not set the innerText of the span; therefore, it does not work as intended.
4. Finally, I have just tried to dynamically create an iframe via JS. After adding the iframe to the DOM (without sandbox attribute), I write the HTML to it, which contains my scripts that I want to be sandboxed in the iframe. In the iframe head, I have a script to sandbox itself. **Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.** (Code below)

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjogden/h28seamv/), but it doesn't give the proper behavior because it is in a nested iframe... I set up a simple page and am testing on my localhost. Here is the code I am using for testing:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Case #2 ~ Does not work in IE -->
<iframe srcdoc="<body><script src='sample1.js'></script><script src='sample2.js'></script></body>" sandbox="allow-scripts">
</iframe>

<!-- Case #3 ~ Does not work in Firefox -->
<iframe src="javascript:&quot;<html><body><script src='sample1.js'></script><script src='sample2.js'></script></body></html>&quot;" sandbox="allow-scripts">
</iframe>

<!-- Case #4 ~ Sandbox maybe not applied? -->
<script>
var i   = document.createElement('iframe');
i.src   = "about:blank";
i.id    = "bryce_iframe";
document.body.appendChild(i);
// iframe added to page

var j = document.getElementById('bryce_iframe').contentDocument;
j.open();

var js = "<html><head>" +
         "<scr"+"ipt>window.top.document.getElementById('bryce_iframe').sandbox = 'allow-scripts';</scr"+"ipt>" +
         "</head><body>" +
         "<p>Hi</p>" +
         "<scr"+"ipt>" +
         "var p = document.createElement('p');" + 
         "p.innerText = 'should throw error'; console.log(p);" +
         "window.top.document.body.appendChild(p);" +
         "</scr"+"ipt>" +
         "</body></html>";
// "window.top.document.body.appendChild(p)" should throw an error because of sandbox

j.write(js);

j.close();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My sample1.js file looks like this:

```
var s = document.createElement('span');
s.innerText = "hi";
window.top.document.body.appendChild(s);
```

My sample2.js file looks like this:

```
var txt = "this doesn't try to break out of iframe";
var s = document.createElement('span');
s.innerText = txt;
document.onload=document.body.appendChild(s);
```

I've been looking for helpful resources about this issue for weeks. It would be amazing to have another set of eyes looking into it with me.

I look forward to collaborating with whoever reaches out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [HTML specification of the sandbox attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox), it warns:

> These flags only take effect when the nested browsing context of the iframe element is navigated.

This implies that dynamically adding/removing/updating the sandbox attribute of an iframe after it loads will not have any effect.

The proper way to do this is to host a different HTML file **on a separate domain** that loads the third party JS. You can reference that HTML file in the `src` attribute of your iframe, and you can include the `sandbox` attribute statically, rather than trying to dynamically add it in JavaScript. Make sure you include `allow-scripts` as a value for the `sandbox` attribute so that the child page is able to load the JS.

The reason you should host the other HTML file on a separate domain is for the browsers that don't support the `sandbox` attribute. Browser support is documented [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_elements_iframe_sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why you are adding the `sandbox` attribute in your inner script in example #4?:

```
"<scr"+"ipt>window.top.document.getElementById('bryce_iframe').sandbox = 'allow-scripts';</scr"+"ipt>" +
```

The sandbox attribute should be added to the parent code:

```
<!-- Case #4 ~ Sandbox maybe not applied? -->
<script>
var i   = document.createElement('iframe');
i.src   = "about:blank";
i.id    = "bryce_iframe";
i['sandbox'] = 'allow-scripts';
document.body.appendChild(i);
```

This will prevent parent access.

Comment: I did that because I figured it was worth a shot. From what I learned by the first few tries, I have two options if I do as you suggest: 1) add sandbox attribute _before_ adding that HTML to the iframe - **won't work because can't write to a sandboxed iframe** 2) add sandbox attribute _after_ adding that HTML to the iframe - **won't work because JS in iframe will execute before sandbox attribute is added** ... PS: I appreciate your help

Comment: You're right. Maybe you could add some sort of browser detection (urgh!) to switch between the first two?

Comment: Neither will fully work for Firefox though :-/
In Firefox, the case #2 that I have in my code halfway works. It will create `<span></span>` but not actually have the text inside of it, leading me to believe that it is not reliable.

Comment: Why do you have to do it i client side?

Comment: What would be the alternative to hosting 3rd-party scripts on a website that do not have DOM manipulation rights?

Comment: You could output the untrusted code server-side, and then use a solution [like this one here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21244925/413180).

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with the same problem. I don't have a good solution either but have 2 more options that don't work on Edge:

Option 1: Blob URL

```
var blob = new Blob([html_string], {type: 'text/html'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var i   = document.createElement('iframe');
i.src = url;
i.sandbox = "allow-scripts";
```

Option 2: Data URL

```
var url = "data:text/html,<html_string>";
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.src = url;
i.sandbox = "allow-scripts";
```