# How can I allow user controlled CSS without introducing XSS?

Tags: css, security, xss, veracode

I have an application where I could customize HTML templates depending on requirement of client. It has a provision of including CSS style scripts when creating a template which would be injected at the end when generating the template. By this way, client/support person could dynamically generate variety of HTML templates.

But when I give this project for a security scan, all the CSS injections are detected as security vulnerabilities (XSS Injections). My Application itself designed based on the CSS injection as it is required to create dynamic HTML template without the involvement of a developer.

Is there a way to prevent XSS security flaws at the same time of achieving application's end result?

Please let me know if there is an alternative way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing untrusted CSS input is an XSS flaw as it could be used for redressing the UI. For example, a malicious user could make their text and content appear to be authoritative text coming from the website itself by dressing it with the same style and positioning.

See the [Google Browser Security Handbook](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Arbitrary_page_mashups_(UI_redressing)) for more information.

There are [also ways to get script to run via CSS](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1#Cascading_stylesheets):

> The risk of JavaScript execution. As a little-known feature, some CSS
>   implementations permit JavaScript code to be embedded in stylesheets.
>   There are at least three ways to achieve this goal: by using the
>   expression(...) directive, which gives the ability to evaluate
>   arbitrary JavaScript statements and use their value as a CSS
>   parameter; by using the url('javascript:...') directive on properties
>   that support it; or by invoking browser-specific features such as the
>   -moz-binding mechanism of Firefox.

- Script execution via `-moz-binding` is available on Firefox 2 and 3. The Google Browser Security Handbook doesn't appear to have been updated since Firefox 3. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613162/413180) indicates this is now fixed so that the XML file has to be readable from your own domain. XBL doesn't seem to be possible in current versions of Firefox.
- In Internet Explorer 10 and earlier [HTML Components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/482088/413180) allow script execution in CSS.

You can mitigate the risk of untrusted content by [implementing an HTML5 sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21244925/413180). Also consider [implementing a Content Security Policy with sanitisation](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/61134/8340) to prevent users from escaping from your CSS context in any way (I haven't seen your code, but I wonder if a user enters `</style>` as part of the CSS, whether it allows them to escape the style tag?).