# How can I execute code that a user inputs into my ACE editor on my page

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using [ACE Editor](http://ace.c9.io/) as my text editor on my page and the user will type in it code.

1. I am looking to execute code that has been entered by the user on or in the browser if         possible. How do I get the input from the editor and utilize the Browsers V8 JavaScript compiler with it?
2. I am then going to try to run it on a Node.js but first I have to learn Node :).

Comment: have you managed to get this work ? curious to know how you did this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's relatively simple to grab some user entered code and run it, with JavaScript. Essentially, you'll grab the code from ACE:

```
var code = editor.getValue();
```

Then use javascript to run it. At the simplest level you can just do:

```
eval(code);
```

However, you [probably don't want to use `eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). Instead you might do something like:

```
// grabbed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/adding-script-element-to-the-dom-and-have-the-javascript-run
var script = document.createElement('script');
try {
  script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  document.body.appendChild(script);
} catch (e) {
  script.text = code;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

This will work. However, it will still cause some problems, as then, the user code could affect your environment. In this scenario, it may not be terrible from a security perspective (unless the user can share their code), but it would be confusing. For that reason, you'll want to [sandbox your code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)).

[This answer explains sandboxing client side javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706409/648494), using `window.postMessage`, you could send javascript to the sandboxed iframe and have it be evaluated there.

If you wish to bring this server-side and execute Node code, you'll need to do sandboxing differently. *On a server, sandboxing is much more of a concern, as the user gets to do a lot more with Javascript and could maliciously interact with your server.* Luckily, there are [a few sandboxes for Node that should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513212/safely-sandbox-and-execute-user-submitted-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Getting code is the easy part just do `code = editor.getValue()`
Simply utilizing V8 compiler is easy too, create iframe and do

```
try {
    var result = iframeWindow.eval(code)
} catch(e) {
    // report error...
}
```

but this won't be very useful since it will be very easy to create infinite loops and break the page.
You can have a look at https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/blob/master/public/js/runner/loop-protect.js#L7 to resolve loop problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. And I will also post the code I already have.