# React - component or a way to have a console that is similar Chrome/Firefox JS console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

I am working on React application that requires executing some JavaScript code in the browser. It has a code editor (using Ace editor), where user can type in some code, press `Run` button to execute the code and see the results output in some console.
What would be a good React "console" component or a way to build a console similar to Chrome/Firefox JS console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most **Naive** way to do it is via the native `eval()` function in Javascript. I'm sure Ace provides some API to get the text in the editor. From there all you need to do is to tie an `eval(*yourEditorText*)` to your button and print it onto the screen.

There are some caveats with that tho. Like if a user prints a for-loop that runs infinitely, your page is gonna crash. Security also becomes a concern. Read this to understand more about the effects of using `eval()` [How can I make external code 'safe' to run? Just ban eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739850/how-can-i-make-external-code-safe-to-run-just-ban-eval/21706409#21706409)

EDIT: If you want to print console messages on to the webpage, you have to do some weird stuff with hijacking the `window.console` object, to get the log messages and then pass it to your React object. Trying to work on a fiddle to do that.

EDIT2: Made the fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/julianljk/qsu5uzxk/

Comment: I am aware of `eval`, what I am looking for is a "console" similar to Chrome or Firefox consoles to display the output of `eval`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log take a look at this!